# How to redirect to other site from onApplicationEvent() in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I have a class:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent>
```

and method which is void:

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent arg0)
```

I would like to redirect to other site

```
if(daysBetweenLocalDates(LocalDate.now(), operator.getDateOfChangePassword()) >= 30)
{
    System.out.println("###DEB forcing operator to change pass because date of change pass is: " + operator.getDateOfChangePassword());
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("redirect:/changePassword");
}
```

but I need `return mav;` and there is problem since `onApplicationEvent` is void. How can I redirect user to another website from that method?

Comment: You don't from an event listener...

Comment: So it's impossible to redirect from Listener?

Comment: A HandlerInterceptor might be a better fit in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Brian Clozel suggested Handler works great!
So I made a handler:

```
package local.vlex.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class VlexAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.sendRedirect("/changePassword");
        }
    }
```

and used it in WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Autowired
VlexAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
```

then:

```
.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().successHandler(successHandler)
```

Thank you @Brian Clozel!